# Draw Maximum Information from Experts to set up Utility Function

Tags: experiment-design, interview

We aim to draw maximum information from CEP-logistics experts to set up a utility function for delivery chain choices for each parcel. The choices / dependent variables are specific transport chains, e.g., delivery only with light commercial vehicle (LCV), LCV with a turnover to cargo bikes, tram with a turnover to cargo bike - in total, six options. The independent variables are parcel size, the distance of the recipient, travel times, emission values, etc. Now, we want to estimate the parameters.

What is statistically the best method if we can only get 5-10 responses from experts? Something like the "Analytic hierarchy process", maybe?

Thank you for your responses.